# Deny access to /lib but allow access to /assets/lib

Tags: nginx, openresty

I'd like to create an nginx rule to deny access (with a 404 so that the attacker doesn't think it exists) to a root directory /lib, but I do not want to include all directories with the word lib such as /assets/lib.

So in other words:

https://www.example.com/lib/* = should be all 404 ...

https://www.example.com/assets/lib/* = should be OK

```
location ~ /lib {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}
```

The above works to block access to all directories that have the word "lib" in them, but that also blocks my "/assets/lib".

Thanks!

Comment: You are using a regex matching location that will match the `/lib` part wherever it is in the request URI. You can use a "start-of-the-string" anchor `location ~ ^/lib { ... }`, but you don't need a regex for your example at all, use a prefix location `location /lib { ... }` instead. You can remove that `deny all;` directive, it does nothing, the `return 404;` one will be executed first.

Comment: About `deny all` and `return 404` directives used together and why `deny all` is useless here - you can read about it in [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1084097/498657) answer.